# Getting height values and positioning in centre with multiple elements with varying heights

Tags: jquery

I am creating a news page and the article is sitting over an image in an overlay box.  I have multiple news items bring printed on a page which are working with a scoller.

The bit i am interested in centering is the figcaption.

```
        <section>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <figure>
                <img src="{news_image}" alt="{title}" width="718" />
                <figcaption>
                    {article}
                    <a href="#close" class="btn-close">X</a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </section> 
        <section>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <figure>
                <img src="{news_image}" alt="{title}" width="718" />
                <figcaption>
                    {article}
                    <a href="#close" class="btn-close">X</a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </section> e.t.c
```

I want to get the height of each img within the figure as well as the height of each figcaption so that i can centre it perfectly over the image.

With one element i can imagine it being quite easy but the confusion for me is how to get Jquery to add the correct values for each.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle? I'm not sure what the page's supposed to look like. Iterating over the $() won't help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this simply by iterating over each section:

```
$('section').each(function(){
    var imgHeight = $(this).find('img').height();
    var captionHeight = $(this).find('figcaption').height();
    {position caption here}
});
```

That should allow you to grab the height of each image and each caption in each section.

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nQCUr/1/

Comment: Would this then be the best way to add CSS?
$(this).find('figcaption').css("color","red");

Comment: I think that would be the way I would change the text color if required

Comment: If you use `$(this)` more than once, it's good to store it into a variable. Andy: yes, that's right. Note that you can add more css values in a single call by `.css({option: 'value', option2: 'value'})`

Comment: Also if you're using the red color across the site, it might be better to define `.red` in your css and use `.addClass('red')` in jQuery